# Cloudinary Error: {"error":{"message":"Missing required parameter - timestamp"}}

Tags: spring, spring-boot, image, file, cloudinary

I am trying to use Cloudinary's `.downloadMulti(String tag, Map options)` to generate a URL to download multiple images as a zip with the same tag. I am generating the URL seemingly just fine, but when I go to the URL, I am met with {"error":{"message":"Missing required parameter - timestamp"}}.

I've researched a bit and I saw that I need to sign the request, but it isn't saying that I'm missing that - just the timestamp. I believe the request is already being signed, just need a proper timestamp. I believe it needs to be within the constructor, but when I called `Util.timestamp()` it isn't recognized as a reference.

My Cloudinary initializer:

```
private final Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(ObjectUtils.asMap(
            "cloud_name", "dxoa7bbix",
            "api_key", "161649288458746",
            "api_secret", "..."));
```

My upload method:

```
public Photo uploadOrderImage(String imageURL, String publicId, Order order, String photoType) throws IOException {
        Map result = cloudinary.uploader().upload(new File(imageURL), ObjectUtils.asMap(
                "public_id", publicId,
                 "tags", order.getId().toString()));
        Photo sellOrderPhoto = new Photo(
                result.get("secure_url").toString(),
                photoType,
                order
        );
        return photoRepository.save(sellOrderPhoto);
    }
```

This is my download method:

```
public String downloadPhotos(String tag) throws IOException {
        return cloudinary.downloadMulti(tag, ObjectUtils.asMap(
                "tags", tag
        ));
    }
```

An example URL my download method returns: Generated URL: [https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dxoa7bbix/image/multi?mode=download&async=false&signature=5f5da549fc78ea3fd50f034cdc76e2cce3089d48&api_key=161649288458746&tag=137×tamp=1638583257](https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dxoa7bbix/image/multi?mode=download&async=false&signature=5f5da549fc78ea3fd50f034cdc76e2cce3089d48&api_key=161649288458746&tag=137%C3%97tamp=1638583257).

Overall, I think the problem is the lack of a timestamp. If you have any ideas, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the parameter is expected to be called `timestamp` but based on the URL you shared, it is actually `×tamp`.

If you want to generate a URL to a ZIP file containing assets that share a particular tag, then you will want to use the [generate_archive](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#generate_archive_method) method and not [multi](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#multi) which provides different functionality.

If you replace the following code:

```
    return cloudinary.downloadMulti(tag, ObjectUtils.asMap(
        "tags", tag
    ));
```

With:

```
    return cloudinary.downloadZip(ObjectUtils.asMap(
        "tags", tag, 
        "resource_type", "image")
    );
```

Then that will generate and return a URL to a ZIP file that will get created when the URL is accessed and contain images from your cloud that contain the `tag` you specified.

The Cloudinary Java SDK you're using will handle the signature/timestamp generation automatically when using any of the built-in methods, therefore, you don't need to make any changes to the SDK code or calculate the signature yourself if using the built-in methods. Signature generation is only necessary if you're not intending to use any of the SDKs but integrate with the Cloudinary API using your own custom code - such as if you're using a language for which a Cloudinary SDK doesn't yet exist. In such cases, if you want to perform authenticated API calls, you will need to [generate authentication signatures](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures) yourself.